# ionic breaking batch file project replication

Tags: windows, cordova, batch-file, ionic-framework

I have created a series of batch files to create a new version of my app.  After each release of my app, I then must create a new version of the app to be able to track (and compare) all the changes from version 1.1 to 1.2. The batch file creates all the necessary directories, copies specific files from version X to version Y, adds plugins, platforms, resources, etc.

Part of the batch file process requires: `ionic start projectName_1.2 tabs`  or eventually `ionic build android`

However, both of those commands actually break the master batch file.  Currently i have to break my batch file into two files...the 2nd one I run after the first breaks out after the `ionic` commands run.  What is causing this and how can I prevent it from happening so I can run the single combined batch file?

Comment: Is `ionic` a batch file?

Comment: no...its a js file `ionic.js` - however, I figured it out.  It should be `call ionic xxxxxxx`

Comment: Yes.  That is why I asked if it was another batch file.  You have to use CALL, otherwise control does not return to the main batch file.  Did not think that was necessary for any other type of script or executable.